# Send Email Types

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Here's my send email function that sends the email however i have two different types of emails (txt, html). The problem is that when it sent to my yahoo address it sends the html which is fine BUT it shows the html code instead of rendering it. How can I fix that.

```
/**
* Send email message of given type (activate, forgot_password, etc.)
*
* @param       string
* @param       string
* @param       array
* @return      void
*/
function sendEmail($template, $type, $subject, $userData)
{
    $this->ci->load->library('email');
    $this->ci->email->from('kowmanagement@kansasoutlawwrestling.com', 'Kansas Outlaw Wrestling');
    $this->ci->email->reply_to('kowmanagement@kansasoutlawwrestling.com', 'Kansas Outlaw Wrestling');
    $this->ci->email->to($userData['email']);
    $this->ci->email->subject($subject);
    $this->ci->email->message($this->ci->load->view($template .'/email/'.$type.'-html', $userData, TRUE));
    $this->ci->email->set_alt_message($this->ci->load->view($template .'/email/'.$type.'-txt', $userData, TRUE));
    $this->ci->email->send();
}
```

Comment: do you set the mailtype to html? is the mail body a complete web page? have you read :http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: I forgot to make its own config file. I did that and it works now.

Comment: @user1406861: Please post your solution and mark it as accepted for the benefit of future visitors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try **PHPMailer**, it is powerful and complete.